# iOS 5 - Admob test vs release

Tags: objective-c, ios5, admob

I am using google admob in my application. I have the following code:

```
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       GAD_SIMULATOR_ID,
                     @"XXXXXXXXXXXXX", nil];
[adMobBannerView loadRequest:r];
```

My question is: How can I avoid calling r.testDevices when my app goes to the market? What is the best practice? Is it necessary to avoid calling it or it realize that it is a release version??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just leave that line in your code for the application that you release into the App Store. Test ads will only be served here to the simulator and to the device with id "XXXXXXXXXXXXX".

All other devices that install the application will be served real ads.